# text html textflow inside or outside Grapics (see scrennshot)

Tags: javascript, html, text

please look at th[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVw7Q.png)is screenshot:

Is it possible tor create such effects only with Html and CSS (eventually with unsing Javascript)

Comment: Yes it is possible  . https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Comment: I dont mean the box-shadow but the text-flow in the first square

Comment: Heck, even two pseudo elements, some border radius and transformations could get you there ... but this is way too broad a question (if we pretend it was more than an _"is it possible"_ in the first place.) Please go read [ask], and start doing your own proper research into how such shapes could be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, using `shape-outside` along with `polygon()` is what you are looking for. It allows us to mark edges of the shape we want to put our text in. Look at my snippet below:

```css
div.main {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 40px -60px 0 0 rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.6);
}

.shape {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.shape::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 0% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.shape>span::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 1%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 100% 50%, 50% 0%);
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>
<div class="main">
  <div class="shape">
    <span>
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
    lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm
    dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet lorem ipusm dolor sit amet
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

- The `div.main` is first rotated `45deg` (clockwise) and the `div.shape` is counter-rotated to original position with `-45deg`.
- Now, `shape-outside` `polygon()` are defined in the pseudo `::before` of `div.shape` and `::after` of `div.shape>span`. This makes a rhombus shape within the main `div.main`.
- The text cannot flow past the shape, and so remains inside it.
- Additional effects like those in photograph also provided.

**UPDATE**: I noticed that the above doesn't work in *Internet Explorer*, though works correctly in *Opera* and *Google Chrome*. For this problem, you can use **browser-specific** style rules, and make the shape a simple rectangle in non-supporting browsers. Read about Browser Specific Rules at [Paul Irish's Website](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/). Excerpts:

```
/***** Attribute Hacks ******/


/* IE6 */

#once {
  _color: blue
}


/* IE6, IE7 */

#doce {
  *color: blue;
  /* or #color: blue */
}


/* Everything but IE6 */

#diecisiete {
  color/**/
  : blue
}


/* IE6, IE7, IE8, but also IE9 in some cases :( */

#diecinueve {
  color: blue\9;
}


/* IE7, IE8 */

#veinte {
  color/*\**/
  : blue\9;
}


/* IE6, IE7 -- acts as an !important */

#veintesiete {
  color: blue !ie;
}


/* string after ! can be anything */


/* IE8, IE9 */

#anotherone {
  color: blue\0/;
}


/* must go at the END of all rules */


/* IE9, IE10 */

@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
  #veintidos {
    color: red
  }
}


/***** Selector Hacks ******/


/* IE6 and below */

* html #uno {
  color: red
}


/* IE7 */

*:first-child+html #dos {
  color: red
}


/* IE8 (Everything but IE 6,7) */

html>
/**/

body #cuatro {
  color: red
}


/* Everything but IE6-8 */

:root *>#quince {
  color: red
}


/* IE7 */

*+html #dieciocho {
  color: red
}


/* IE 10+ */

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  #veintiun {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works in Opera Too. Which Browser are you using @MaximilianLindner?

Comment: I Updated the answer, look at it now.